# Kubernetes nginx ingress prevent response from default-backend on https

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Currently with the nginx ingress in kubernetes it will always respond to direct IP requests (i.e. http://1.1.1.1) with the default-backend and there doesn't appear to be a way of disabling it.

Worse, it will also respond to https://1.1.1.1 in the same manner with a self-signed cert (you can override it but obviously even if you provide a valid cert, it still won't be valid against an IP request)  This is a major security vulnerability that causes any site using Kubernetes and nginx ingress to fail PCI compliance network scans.

AND there is no way of overriding this behavior in your ingress defintion.

I'm trying to figure out how without hacking to be able to prevent the default-backend from responding to https on an IP request given that there is never a case in a production environment where this would be secure and will always cause PCI failure.

How does one get the nginx ingress to not respond to https on an IP request?

Comment: could you post your ingress ?

Comment: I could but I've confirmed that it isn't my ingress. It's the way nginx handles non-SNI requests. your ingress definition will be ignored and it will always go to the default backend and there doesn't appear to be a way to disable the default-backend from responding to https which is insecure by definition on an IP request.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally worked around this for PCI purposes. It isn't satisfying but it works and they don't freak out. Just apply the default certificate as the same for your site. It isn't valid, but because it comes from a valid signing authority PCI scans allow it to go through.

Which is lame, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I tried googling and tested several ideas but non of them worked.

I also tried reading nginx-ingress code but didn't find anything satisfying.

I think that the best thing you could do is to ask developers.
Just open an [issue on nginx-ingress github repository](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues).

Comment: Here's the ticket. Not at all satisfying given that you can't actually create a PCI compliant K8s environment as it stands right now: https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/971